# Angular double curly braces expressions being executed multiple times on mouse down and up

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

In our Angular app, given code like the following:

```
<div>{{ aGetProperty }}</div>

<div>{{ aMethod() }}</div>
```

Whenever I click anywhere on the page, these expressions are evaluated multiple times. That is, if I put a console.log('hello') in aMethod, every time I press down on either the left or right mouse button, hello is outputted to console multiple times and again multiple times on mouse up.

Anyone know what could be causing this issue? I have not bound any click, mouse up/down events for the component or anything above it (as far as I can tell). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular actually patches the browsers's low-level API: for example the addEventListener is patched to check for changes in DOM and rerender the view. Thus, when you click on the DOM elements Angular will run change detection and your method calls in DOM will get executed. In other words: it's a bad practice to bind methods from DOM - unless it's explicitly an on/click event - because the method will get executed on each change detection in lifecycle. Of course, sometimes you'd indeed want some of your methods to fire on each change, but make sure that's exactly what you want.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but surely we made a mistake some where because clicking any where (even in a blank area on the page) causes these to fire multiple times. Like 4-6 times on mouse down and 4-6 times on mouse up.

Comment: In plain JS, I can just do a global search for mousedown, touchstart, etc., what should I look for here?

Comment: it's not about the click - it's about events on the page and the fact that Angular will rerender the view when the events trigger. Here's an example: just go resizing the browser window and you'll again see the `aMethod()` firing its 'hello' - without any clicks on page itself. So, in short, don't bind methods in template, because they'll probably be triggered on each change. Bind the variables and handle their values in the right Angular lifehooks.